# save mysql table as csv modifying file some of the cell data in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need to download a mysql table as a csv file. Okay, Now thats no big thing.
But I need to modify the cell contents when I download it. For eg. In the table male, female and others are denoted as 1 2 and 3 respectively. But the downloaded excel csv file should contain "Male" "female" and "others" in the gender field. 
I tried calling some php functions within the code. But it didnt work.
 Is it possible? 
Can you help guys?

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bus",$conn);

$query = "SELECT * FROM booking";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num_column = mysql_num_fields($result);        

$csv_header = '';
for($i=0;$i<$num_column;$i++) {
    $csv_header .= '"' . mysql_field_name($result,$i) . '",';
}   
$csv_header .= "\n";

$csv_row ='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    for($i=0;$i<$num_column;$i++) {
          //echo $i;                               this and the next line doesnt execute
         //echo '<script>myFunction()</script>'; 
        $csv_row .= '"' . $row[$i] . '",';
    }
    $csv_row .= "\n";
}
/* Download as CSV File */
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toy_csv.csv');
echo $csv_header . $csv_row;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You comment in the code that 'this and the next line doesnt execute' - do you mean `$csv_row .= '"' . $row[$i] . '",';` and `$csv_row .= "\n";` or the lines that are commented out?

Comment: At first glance the code looks like it should run, and that your query maybe doesn't actually return any rows. It would be good to know how many new line characters get output. It would help if you edited the question to include the exact output that you do get.

Comment: Thanks Theo for the concern. But the answer below solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other fields that you expect for,

but this is how you will get the gender.

```
SELECT

IF (
    `booking`.gender = 1,
    "Male",

IF (
    `booking`.gender = 2,
    "Female",
    "Other"
)
) as gender
FROM
    `booking`;
```